# Воспроизвести звук в фоновом режиме. Приложение для ходьбы

Tags: ios, swift, background, таймер

Создаю приложение для ходьбы. Не могу решить одну проблему. 
Сначала объясню суть работы приложения. Есть программа тренировок для ходьбы из последовательных упражнений, например:

- Разминка 5 мин
- Ходьба 15 мин
- Бег 5 мин

Основное предназначение в том, что пользователь включает музыку (или нет), переводит данное приложение в фоновый режим и начинает тренировку. А мне нужно, чтобы по истечению каждого таймера, т.е. сначала 5 мин, потом 15 мин и т.д. приложение об этом уведомляло. Для воспроизведения звукового уведомления я использую `AVSpeechSynthesizer` (может быть не самый лучший выбор), т.е. когда срабатывает триггер таймера, приложение явно сообщает: "Разминка завершена, переходим к ходьбе". На переднем фоне все работает безупречно, а как настроить работу в фоновом режиме пока без понятия. Все необходимые Capabilities подключил. 
А есть способ воспроизвести `AVSpeechSynthesizer` через локальные уведомления `UNUserNotificationCenter`? Мне самое главное воспроизвести речь после истечения таймера. Буду рад любой помощи, простите за сумбур.

Answer (score 1):

После закрытия программы у вас есть вроде бы 30 секунд и потом Apple отключит любой функционал вашей программы .У вас есть PushNotification  (local и з сервера) которые могут присылать уведомления в заданное время (или день и т.д.) . Я бы посоветовал придумать обходной путь и например ставить весь прогресс на паузу  ,сохранять в UserDefaults и предупреждать что программу не следует закрывать  иначе прогресс потеряется полностью если закрыть во время упражнений. Или что то другое. ПОтому что как бы вы не старались писать код и придумывать что то , если пользователь принудительно закроет приложение, то никакой код выполнятся не будет .

Comment: Придумал обходной путь. 
Создаю очередь из mp3 файлов так, что по таймингу у меня воспроизводится нужный файл, а в промежутках "играет" пустая звуковая дорожка

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал поискать в google следующее: "swift AVSpeechSynthesizer in background".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183591/avspeechsynthesizer-in-background-mode

Comment: Нужно, чтобы в бэкграунде срабатывал таймер, сначала 5, потом 15 и тд, и по окончании каждого таймера воспроизводилась музыка. Проблема в том, что в фоновом режиме по истечению некоторого короткого времени все процессы замораживаются ради экономии, соответственно таймер также перестает работать

Comment: Я бы смотрел в сторону LocalNotification https://medium.com/@Debash/local-notifications-with-swift-4-d370c90a6e0e, https://swiftbook.ru/post/koposhilka/24/, вообще на swiftbook.ru много интересного.